# Delphi Incorporating Tabs

Tags: delphi, tabs

I am using XE2 and am trying to incorporate tabs into my Form GUI application and had no idea I would have this much trouble with something so simple..lol.

Anyways...

I have a TTabSet named TTabSet1..

When I try adding a listview to the first tab ONLY it appears on ALL tabs..
Example:

Tab1:

[image]

Tab2:

[image]

In the IDE:

[image]

Should I use another component rather than TTabSet?
Also when using TTabSet, inside the IDE I cannot change tabs in order to add components to the other tabs...

I am sorry if you guys have better things to do other than answer my n00b questions lol, but any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288754/ttabset-vs-ttabcontrol-vs-tpagectrl-ttabsheet

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `TTabControl` typically involves writing an [OnChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabControl.OnChange) event handler to dynamically hide/show (or destroy/create) child controls. To make your life easier, you could create a separate frame for each tab, and simply create and show the relevant frame when the user clicks on a tab, and free the previous one.

`TPageControl` may be easier to use since you can simply create and populate all the tabs at design time (right-click the page control and select "New Page" to create a new tabsheet). At runtime they are all created when the form is created. The page control manages hiding and showing for you automatically. The downside may be that memory is used for all elements, including the hidden ones, during the whole lifetime of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try adding a list view to the first tab ONLY it appears on ALL tabs.

In that case it sounds like the component you need is a `TPageControl`. Each page of a page control has different content.

To add a new page to a `TPageControl`, right-click the `TPageControl` object and choose **New Page**.

---

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Tabs.TTabSet) for `TTabSet` states:

> Tab set controls are commonly used to display tabbed pages within a dialog box. `TTabSet` is provided for backward compatibility. Use `TTabControl` component in 32-bit Windows applications.

So, even if `TTabSet` was the right type of control for you, you should be using `TTabControl` anyway. The choice between `TTabControl` and `TPageControl` is resolved as follows:

1. Do you want each page to show the same controls, albeit with possibly different data inside those controls? If so then use `TTabControl`.
2. Do you want each page to show different controls? If so then use `TPageControl`.

Comment: ok, well i have tried both.. :/

TPageControl: I could not find anywhere to edit the tabs/pages in properties.. :/

And TTabControl gives me the same issues as in the op..

Sorry again if im being a noob :/

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff

I think TPageControl is correct for me, but i cannont seem to find how to edit the "pages"/tabs...

as in where to add new ones..

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff

It doesn't help me much...
This is the properties i can edit in TPageControl, I cannot add new pages/tabs, etc..
http://gyazo.com/bd05bb187df17ee33ad767090a9c35de.png?1342170742

http://gyazo.com/2ce56267e89bf46ba6073718ead4a51a.png?1342171245

Sorry again, i know this may be simple to some but it is driving me absolutely insane! :/

Comment: @user1512695: Use right click on the page control and then "New Page". That will create a TTabSheet control (a new tab) on the PageControl that has its own properties like "Caption".

Comment: Exactly, the TPageControl is only a container for several TTabSheets.

Comment: @user1512695 Hardly. It's far from obvious that you need to right click the control in order to add pages. I trust you are back on track now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TChromeTabs](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs).

TChromeTabs is a comprehensive implementation of Google Chrome's tabs.

Supports:

- Delphi 6 - Delphi DX10.4 Sydney with High-DPI support
- FreePascal/Lazarus (Alpha)